# How to check if a position is along a defined route via Here Maps SDK?

Tags: maps, position, here-api, heremaps

Does Here Maps SDK contains any functionality that can check if the current position of a truck is within an area along a defined route?

Comment: The 4.x HERE SDK provides a GeoCorridor that wraps an area around a route, or just a list of coordinates: https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-sdk-navigate/4.8.2.0/api_reference/index.html ... this can be used to search for places along a route, but it does not allow to do a bounding box check for specific coordinates. If you just want to know if coordinates are located within any rectangular area, maybe consider to do simple collision detection math.

Answer (score 0):

SDK for Android performs Map Matching automatically when it needs to match a raw position to the road network, e.g. during drive guidance, where there may be inaccuracies in the road rendering or GPS data. Map matching also supports instances where the GPS signal is lost while entering a road tunnel. The position is extrapolated and updated based on the driver’s speed and knowledge of the tunnel layout.

In general, you can use any custom positioning data by implementing the LocationDataSource class and set it by calling PositioningManager.setDataSource(LocationDataSource) before starting the positioning manager.

With the help of positioning provided by Here SDK, at the App level, the current position along the route can be plotted.

https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/3.18/dev_guide/topics/positioning-intro.html

Comment: Hi, is this possible to Explore SDK as well?